# "Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:" when using conda install pytorch=0.3.0 torchvision=0.2.0 cuda90

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm following [this](https://github.com/rowanz/neural-motifs) git repo and trying to install the requirements as they asked. I'm running the command:
`conda install pytorch=0.3.0 torchvision=0.2.0 cuda90 -c pytorch` and getting the error:

```
Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
pytorch=0.3.0 -> libgcc-ng -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
python=3.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
```

It also says:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pytorch=0.3.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']
  - torchvision=0.2.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.6
```

I tried changing my python to be 3.7 but that didn't work either-- got the following error:

```
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
pytorch=0.3.0 -> libgcc-ng -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
python=3.7 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
```

The git repo clearly says "Install python3.6 and pytorch 3" using `conda install pytorch=0.3.0 torchvision=0.2.0 cuda90 -c pytorch`. So I'm not sure where is the issue.